# I need to absolute position an element but can't get the height of the SafeArea in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need to absolutely position an item right under my AppBar().  I can get the height of my appbar, however, it sits under a SafeArea() which is defined in a different file.  How do I get access to the height of the SafeArea()?

Comment: On default, it should be positioned right under the AppBar. Just delete the `Center()` widget when you make a `flutter create app`

Comment: The reason it is absolutely positioned, is because it is being invoked via a call to showGeneralDialog() -- it is basically a customized drop down dialog/menu that appears beneath a users avatar when pressed:

`showGeneralDialog(
      context: context,
      pageBuilder: (BuildContext buildContext, Animation<double> animation,
          Animation<double> secondaryAnimation) {
        return
        Stack(children: <Widget>[
            Positioned(child: 
         _settingsMenu(),
         right: 0.0, top: _getHeight())])`

Comment: Can you specify the widget tree? Other file is not that helpful

Comment: Actually turned out to be a little easier than I thought.  For those trying to do the same thing, once you have the RenderBox (`RenderBox box = _key.currentContext.findRenderObject();` you can then do `var p = box.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);`